# Parsing WP Web Scraping Data with Regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, web-scraping

Im using Wordpress plugin "WP Web Scraper" To easily gather some data from a site. The function wpws_get_content returns the result "Raised(number%)" I want to clean this up to just the number. Ive managed to return (90%) with the following code

```
<p id="number1"><?php echo wpws_get_content('http://my.sportrelief.com/sponsor/sachazarb', '#totalizer_percent', array( 'replace_query' => '/Raised/', 'replace_query_type' => 'regex', 'replace_with' => ' ', ) ); ?></p>
```

I cant work it out further. Its also, strangly, returning duplicate data, ie

```
<!--
 Start of web scrap (created by wp-web-scraper)
 Source URL: http://my.sportrelief.com/sponsor/sachazarb
 Query: #totalizer_percent (cssselector)
 Other options: Array
(
    [headers] => 
    [cache] => 60
    [useragent] => WPWS bot (http://windreeladprint.com)
    [timeout] => 2
    [on_error] => error_show
    [output] => html
    [glue] => 

    [eq] => 
    [gt] => 
    [lt] => 
    [query_type] => cssselector
    [remove_query] => 
    [remove_query_type] => cssselector
    [replace_query] => /Raised/
    [replace_query_type] => regex
    [replace_with] =>  
    [basehref] => 1
    [a_target] => 
    [callback_raw] => 
    [callback] => 
    [debug] => 1
    [charset] => UTF-8
)
--><span id="totalizer_percent" class="percent">  (90%)</span><span id="totalizer_percent" class="percent">  (90%)</span><!--
 End of web scrap
 WPWS Cache Control: Remote-fetch via WP_Http
 Computing time: 1.306 seconds
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex `Raised\((\d+)%\)` and replace with first captured group using `\1` or `$1`.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dW9iR0/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks noob that works for removing the excess, the captured group is still returning a duplicate entry but i think that may be a problem with the plugin rather than a php error. Cheers.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by duplicate entry ?

Comment: It was returning multiple results for the ID however on closer inspection of the source I have found they had repeated their code on the page and hidden it with display none. So there were infact two #totalizer_percent elements in the source.

Comment: Okay. I hope this solution helped you. If you want to add anything to solution be my guest.